# Nagios: Could not resolve hostname

Tags: nagios

My setup:

`hosts.cfg` - contains definitions for each host under monitoring, e.g.:

```
define host{
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               rdss-vpn
        display_name            VPN
        address                 54.***.***.176
        }
```

`hosts_groups.cfg` - define groups:

```
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name   rdss-service-server
        alias            RDSS services
        members          [...],  rdss-vpn
        }
```

`services.cfg`:

```
define service{
        use                             local-service
        hostgroup_name                  rdss-web-server, rdss-service-server
        service_description             Memory usage
        check_command                   check_linux_memory!50!80
        notifications_enabled           1
        }
```

And `check_linux_memory` in `commands.cfg`:

```
define command{
        command_name    check_linux_memory
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTNAME$ -c check_linux_memory -a '-f -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$'
        }
```

Here is example of host, where `check_linux_memory` works:

```
define host{
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               www.dev.domain.com
        display_name            DEV
        address                 54.***.***.136
        }
```

It's group:

```
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name   rdss-web-server
        alias            RDSS web servers
        members          www.dev.domain.com, www.qa.domain.com, www.staging.domain.com
        }
```

Problem is with few new added hosts, like `rdss-vpn` - Nagios won't get it's IP from hosts (please note - I have few other servers (also in groups) in `check_linux_memory` - all works).

Instead - I have an error in `nagios.log`:

> [1437473407] SERVICE ALERT: rdss-vpn;Memory usage;WARNING;HARD;4;(No
>   output on stdout) stderr: Could not resolve hostname rdss-vpn: Name or
>   service not known

Comment: It might be a bit pedantic, but your  [question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) appears to be missing an actual question with a question mark "`?`" :-)  . - Please improve your question or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Comment: Well, tried to resolve the domain name with dig or host?

Comment: @sebix Nagios must get IP from `address` in `define host` - correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrote your check command to use `$HOSTNAME$` instead of `$HOSTADDRESS$`.

This happens to work for your other hosts, because they are named with FQDNs (e.g., www.dev.domain.com). It doesn't work for `rdss-vpn` because that's not a valid hostname from the perspective of your Nagios box.

You should use the address, not the hostname, in checks. This removes DNS as a dependency for Nagios checks. If you really need to use a hostname instead of the IP, put the hostname in as the host address.

Also, traditionally one would just pass the check to `check_nrpe` as an ARG, like `check_nrpe!check_memory` or `check_nrpe!check_memory!50 80`. But it's up to you, ultimately.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! That's exactly what I need! I remember about Nagios own documation - but it's located on Sourceforge - and unavailable last.... one? two weeks?

Comment: I normally link to the docs, but yes they're mostly unavilable currently. Google has most of it cached, if you know the exact page you need.